# Adding content to a div from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to load a script that contains the content of a div on my html page. I know this is possible, but I am struggling to understand how to do it. Here is my html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="script.js"> </script>
<div id="helloWorld"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What would script.js have to be for the html page to display something? I was thinking something like this (I know it's incorrect, I'm a beginner at javascript.

```
function showText()
{
    $("#helloWorld").html("<p> Hello World! </p>")
    $("#helloWorld").show();

}
showText()
```

Can someone tell me whether or not I'm on the right track, and how I could fix this? Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Seems fine although you don't need the line ending .show(). Have you reference jQuery?

Comment: I've read quite a bit, I'm not sure why I cannot get this working :S

Answer (score 3):

Your code is jQuery:

```
$("#helloWorld").html("<p> Hello World! </p>")
$("#helloWorld").show();
```

and you don't need `$("#helloWorld").show();`.

In plain JavaScript,

```
function showText()
{
    document.getElementById("helloWorld").innerHTML="<p> Hello World! </p>";
}
showText()
```

But remember to call `showText()` after the loading of the div in the DOM! (For example, call it just before `</body>` tag).

Then,

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
showText();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And script.js:

```
function showText(){
    document.getElementById("helloWorld").innerHTML="<p> Hello World! </p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it does nothing (I assume) becaue your script tag is before the div itself.
If you're using JQuery, you should put your initial code into the ready function, in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  showText();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When your script loads, the HTML element "`#helloWorld`" still doesn't exist.

Use [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) like this:

```
function showText() {
    $("#helloWorld").html("<p> Hello World! </p>")
    $("#helloWorld").show();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    showText();
});
```

Comment: thanks, will try this! And thanks to all the other answers as well

Answer (score 0):

the syntax you are trying to use requires JQuery. You can download the latest JQuery library here
http://jquery.com/

Then you can use the following in order to add text to your div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var showText = function(){
    $("#helloWorld").html("<p> Hello World! </p>")  
    $("#helloWorld").show();
  };    
  showText();
});
```

Edited: I have added in the $ character at the start of (document), also, it is not necessary to have the `.show()` function on your div as it is already visible. If you do however set that div's display to none, you should use `.show()` to display the div.

Comment: You forgot a `$` before (document). I would add it, but I can't as I need to change 6 characters.

Comment: Apologies, h2oooo is correct. Ensure to add the $ in front of your (document) to instantiate the use of jquery